# How to increase/decrease the resolution of a downloaded image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, resolution

I want to know is there a way to increase/decrease the resolution of a downloaded image? I am getting the image from the web using an URL. But the image is displayed with really low resolution so is it possible to increase it?

I am getting the image using the following code:

```
class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
ImageView bmImage;


public GetImage (ImageView bmImage) 
{
    this.bmImage = bmImage;        
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try 
    {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
{
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the resolution of a photo you've downloaded. That is CSI territory. However, you can scale it up, so that it covers a larger area, if that's what you're after. (the image is still blurred)

The way you do that is usually using something like [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)